# Reference for the delooping of groups (or rings)

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, ct.category-theory

This [nlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping#delooping_of_a_group_to_a_groupoid) defines the delooping groupoid of a group, but it does not provide a reference. I am using deloopings of rings, and I would like to refernce to a more classical source.

Could you please recommend a reference for the delooping functor? Btw, where were deloopings of groups (or rings) first considered?

Comment: To be honest: I always found it strange to distinguish between a group $G$ and the corresponding one-object groupoid. The data are equivalent, and I have never seen a situation where this is really necessary (does someone know such a situation?). Similarly, it is not really important to distinguish between a poset and the induced thin category, but *this* seems to be commonly accepted and there is no extra notation. And even more confusingly, $BG$ also denotes (more often, actually) the classifying space of $G$.

Comment: @HeinrichD - The category of groups is not equivalent to the 2-category of one-object groupoids.  It follows, for instance, that a "sheaf of groups" is not the same as "a (2-)sheaf of one-object groupoids" -- the latter are also called "gerbes", and not every gerbe is *globally* the delooping of a group.

Comment: @MikeShulman: There is no category which is equivalent to a 2-category, because equivalences are only defined between objects of the same type. The 2-category of groups is equal to the 2-category of one-object groupoids. For the same reason, it is clear that sheaves do not coincide with 2-sheaves, regardless of their values.

Comment: @HeinrichD It's standard to identify a category with the 2-category obtained from it by adding only identity 2-cells.  But the point is the same whether you phrase it as "the category of groups is not equivalent to the 2-category of one-object groupoids" or "groups form a 1-category whereas one-object groupoids form a 2-category".

Comment: Of course, you can define a 2-category whose objects "are" groups that is equivalent to the 2-category of one-object groupoids, just as you can define a category whose objects "are" groups that is equivalent to the category of sets.  But that sort of chicanery robs definitions of all meaning.  The *natural* categorical structure formed by groups is a 1-category, whereas the natural categorical structure formed by one-object groupoids is a 2-category, and the two are not the same in any sense.

Comment: @HeinrichD: Regardless of their categories, or 2-categories, one distinguishes between a group and **a** corresponding one-object groupoid because they are different! As you know, the latter is given by a group and a choice of a one-element set of objects. Unless you consider a model for set theory which admits a unique one-element set, the two notions are different, and a distinction is needed. The same way one distinguishes between different isomorphic groups, and between small and essentially small categories,...they usually serve the same purpose, yet they are different.

Comment: @HeinrichD: The situation for posets is different, as you have a canonical choice of the set of objects, regardless of the foundations. For the notation, it is natural, the classifying space functor $\mathbf{Grp}\to \mathbf{sSet}$ is the composition of the delooping functor $\mathbf{Grp}\to \mathbf{Cat}$ with the Nerve embedding $\mathbf{N}:\mathbf{Cat}\to\mathbf{sSet}$.

Comment: @user337830: Yes groups do not coincide with one-object groupoids from the restricted point of view of ZFC set theory, but: there is an isomorphism of categories between groups (and homomorphisms) and one-object groupoids (and functors). As is well-known, isomorphic categories can be identified without any harm.

Comment: @HeinrichD: I think you mean an equivalence of categories. How is it an isomorphism?

Comment: Oups, yes, it is an equivalence of categories.

Answer (score 1):

Groupoids where introduced probably for the first time in Brandt's 1927 paper "Über eine Verallgemeinerung des Gruppenbegriffes", which you can read (if you know German) [here](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PID=GDZPPN002271125). It was conceived from the beginning as a generalization of the concept of a group, namely as a group with partially defined multiplication and inverse maps. There is no real necessary distinction between a group and the corresponding groupoid (see also my comment above). On the second page of his paper, Brandt simply says "Gruppoide vom Rang 1 sind offenbar Gruppen", which translates to "groupoids with one object are evidently groups" (and from the context it is clear that this is meant vice versa). Notice that Brandt defines the rank of a groupoid to be the number of objects (which he calls "Einheiten", i.e. units).